# Parsing a Json and retreating data from it on React Native

Tags: json, react-native

iam working with a json and i dont know how to retrieve data from it after parsing.

```
{
"records": [
    {
        "1": "salle de bain , Wc"
    },
    {
        "2": "cuisine : armoires , sols"
    },
    {
        "3": "chambre : poussière , changer le lit , sols"
    },
    {
        "4": "salon et salle à manger : poussière sols "
    },
    {
        "5": "fenêtres "
    },
    {
        "6": " four , frigo "
    },
    {
        "7": "lessive"
    },
    {
        "8": "repassage"
    },
    {
        "9": "commissions avec ou sans client "
    },
    {
        "10": "autre"
    }
]
```

}

i can read items of the record array but i can not get inside items

```
    {
    "1": "salle de bain , Wc"
},
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried to read the data? After working on the data that you have provided, I am able to read the individual objects just fine like so `data.records[0]["1"]`, `data.records[1]["2"]`

Comment: I did not know that this is a possibility, thank you, I can accept this as an answer